# Get a rectangle area from a picture by Python

Tags: python, opencv

How can I get a rectangle area from a picture by Python?

original picture:

[image]

the ideal result:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to decide what to crop - have you got the coordinates, do you want to detect the starburst, find the purple square, or what?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question. And try to be more clear to explain your question. You may visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please check this similar question as a start: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817442/18667225

Comment: Also consider that due to perspective and lens distortion, that is not technically a rectangle.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).