# How to efficiently detect the center of clusters in an image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

So, I'm trying to find the centers of the white clusters with OpenCV in the next frame:

[image: *screenshot made with OpenCV imshow()*]

I've already tried the HoughGradient function, but it's results were inconsistent, since these clusters weren't circle-like shapes in all frames. Any other suggestions?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options.

1. Use connected components to find the blobs, and because you know
   they are circular do some estimation about their centers. The
   `drawcontours` function on the OpenCV documentation has a good
   example of how to find connected components using contours: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours
2. If you know that your blobs are white / white-ish, you can find the indices of all the pixels that are close in color to white / white-ish, and manually reconstruct each set of indices into a connected component.

(potentially related post: [OpenCV Object Detection - Center Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279410/opencv-object-detection-center-point?rq=1))

Answer (score 0):

as @berak pointed out, you can use moments to find centroid of blobs

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

Point getCentroid( InputArray Points )
{
    Point Coord;
    Moments mm = moments( Points, false );
    double moment10 = mm.m10;
    double moment01 = mm.m01;
    double moment00 = mm.m00;
    Coord.x = int(moment10 / moment00);
    Coord.y = int(moment01 / moment00);
    return Coord;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Mat src = imread( argv[1] );

    Mat gray;
    cvtColor( src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    gray = gray > 127;

    Mat nonzeropixels;
    findNonZero( gray, nonzeropixels );

    Point pt = getCentroid( nonzeropixels );
    rectangle(src, pt,pt, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

    imshow("result",src);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

test images & results : ( green dot is centroid of white blobs )

[image] 
[image]

[image]
[image]